# Attending bio-metric appointment for UK visitor visa with family

Tags: visas, uk, family, vfs-global

1. I and my wife got the appointment on the same day but different times (10:30 am & 12:30 pm) - in San Francisco. But our son got the appointment 2 days later. Can all three of us go together during my appointment date/time? Will they allow that?
2. After the bio-metric appointment do I have to send the documents to the decision making center myself? Or if I purchase the VFS service for round-trip courier, will the Premium Application Center do it themselves? This is not clear from their web site.
3. Doesn't the Bronze package that VFS offers include the round-trip courier service too? Or do I have t purchase that separately?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is scoped only to the San Francisco VFS and assumes that all applicants qualify for the premium service...

> I and my wife got the appointment on the same day but different times
>   (10:30 am & 12:30 pm) - in San Francisco. But our son got the
>   appointment 2 days later. Can all three of us go together during my
>   appointment date/time? Will they allow that?

The entire family should show up together.

> After the bio-metric appointment do I have to send the documents to
>   the decision making center myself? Or if I purchase the VFS service
>   for round-trip courier, will the Premium Application Center do it
>   themselves? This is not clear from their web site.

The VFS will do this for you if you purchase the premium service

> Doesn't the Bronze package that VFS offers include the round-trip
>   courier service too? Or do I have t purchase that separately?

It is inclusive

Comment: >>Doesn't the Bronze package that VFS offers include the round-trip courier service too? Or do I have t purchase that separately?

>It is inclusive
Thanks Gayot! 

In the “What to do next?” section of visa application web site, it still asks to purchase courier service. So, I’m confused if the Bronze package indeed includes the round-trip courier service also. The Bronze package description also doesn’t say about the courier service. Can someone clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Here's my update: I and  my whole family went for the bio-metrics appointment on Friday. They let all of us do it at the same time. Thanks Gayot for the reply. Appreciate it! Also confirmed that the Bronze package indeed include round-trip courier service, though the visa application form says (just beneath the Bronze package) that you MUST purchase courier service separately. So, all good so far.

Comment: @Rajesh Gayot is the master at this; in appreciation, you can 'accept' his answer, the tick mark below the down arrow.